# How to prevent overscrolling/quick scrolling in scroll function that fixes a title to a specific point

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpw2yauo/) demonstrating the issue:

I have created a scroll function that is supposed to make a title appear to scroll up over a fixed image, up to a certain point on screen and then fix into place, then scroll up with the unfixed image. A bunch of text below will scroll up under the image.

The function does this by listening for `(headlineTop <= triggerPoint)`. Really when headlineTop == triggerPoint, the background image should unfix and scroll along with the headline.

Here is the code, which features 2 different approaches to unfixing the image.

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

        let triggerPoint = 50;
        let headline = document.getElementById('headline');
        let image = document.getElementById('image');
        let content = document.getElementById('content');

        let headlineTop = headline.getBoundingClientRect().top;

console.log(headlineTop +" "+ triggerPoint)
        if ((headlineTop <= triggerPoint)&&(isFixed)) { 

             let buff = triggerPoint - headlineTop

             //Approach #1 
             headline.style.transform = "translateY(" + buff + "px)"
             content.style.transform = "translateY(" + buff + ")"
            

            //Approach #2
            //resizeMargin(mainContent, image, headline, buff)

            image.style.position = 'absolute';
            image.style.top = window.scrollY + 'px';
            isFixed = false;
        }else if((headlineTop >= triggerPoint)&&(!isFixed)){ // loaded at start
            image.style.position = 'fixed';
            image.style.top = '0';
            isFixed = true;
        }
    });
```

This actually works if you scroll slow enough that headlineTop == triggerPoint or close to it. But if users scroll too quickly, `headlineTop` gets captured too late and the text below scrolls too far up and over the image because the image doesn't unfix in time.

This problem is demonstrated in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpw2yauo/). The issue occurs with both approaches I have (translating the headline and changing the margin top). To see the issue, scroll down really fast and notice the text below overlaps the image, and the headline is too high. In contrast, if you scroll slowly, it works as expected.

Is there a way to get it to work as expected, even when the user scrolls fast?

Comment: I get the feeling you IntersectionObserver could be what you're looking for - though, I've seen this sort of effect done with pure CSS too (kevin powell css parallax)